# Does a DB operation inside a method client stub only affect the local DB?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Given a method definition on both the client and the server,

`server/method.js` :

```
Meteor.methods({
  updatePost: function(post) {
    Posts.update//...        A
   }
 })
```

`client/method.js` :

```
Meteor.methods({
  updatePost: function(post) {
    Posts.update//...        B
    PostStats.update//...    C
   }
 })
```

From there on two chains of events can occur:

1. - B and C update local DB
   - Then A update server DB
   - Then server DB sync to local
   - Thus, **PostStatus remains unchanged**.

Or:

2. - B and C update local DB
   - Then B and C update server DB (using Allow/Deny hooks)
   - Then A update server DB
   - Then server DB sync to local?
   - Thus, **PostStatus changed** (if `PostStatus.Allow` returns true).

Which of the two happens?

Comment: Actually 3. It should be easy to create a demo app to see for yourself and publish your findings here :)